# VBA Excel Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint") number of copies?

Tags: vba, excel, printing, ms-word

i am writing on a short excel vba function to print multiple word documents.

I need to use this code:

```
...
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")   
Set wordObj = WordApp.documents.Open(file)
...
wordObj.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
```

to show the "Backstage" Print and Preview Dialog, and prompt the user to confirm the print.

However the number of copies should be set by the function and if possible not be changeable by the user.

I couldn't find anything usefull searching the web. Does anybody know if it's possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have MS Word 2010 running.

Once in Backstage view, I can use SendKeys to type "alt", "P", "N", "2" to set the number of copies. Eg.:

```
...
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
SendKeys "%PN2", False
```

This sets the number of copies to 2.  The user can change the number of copies though.